# How to modify android's default (original) contact addition code

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app where I need to execute a piece of code whenever user adds a new contact. The solution for this is to use ContentObserver to get notified and then execute the code but for this I need to run the observer service in background which in turn will affect battery life of user's handset.
Instead can I extend the original contact addition code provided by android so that after storing contact in contact db it will execute my code. In this way task becomes efficient.
Is it possible?